# Subtract downpayment from total amount

Tags: php, mysql, database, shopping-cart, opencart

i had created opencart ecommerce checkout system...

i had added a extra field for each products, so when i checkout products i want Subtract my total downpayment amount from total amount of cart....

```
example for my cart
product1 10,    downpayment 5  (number means US dollar)
product1 15,    downpayment 8

my total amount is 25
total Downpayment is 13
```

i want Subtract downpayment from total amount and echo this value below total amount...
if got results it will be like this:

```
total amount      = 25 
downpayment       = 13 
remaining balance = 12
```

anybody please help me.??
sory my english not perfect... i am new in PHP...

i had already created product table from my database..
given below, its a uploaded product fields...

```
===Database q8marketz

== Table structure for table product

|------
|Field|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**product_id**//|int(11)|No|
|model|varchar(64)|No|
|downpayment|varchar(32)|No|
|sku|varchar(64)|No|
|upc|varchar(12)|No|
|ean|varchar(14)|No|
|jan|varchar(13)|No|
|isbn|varchar(13)|No|
|mpn|varchar(64)|No|
|location|varchar(128)|No|
|quantity|int(4)|No|0
|stock_status_id|int(11)|No|
|image|varchar(255)|Yes|NULL
|manufacturer_id|int(11)|No|
|shipping|tinyint(1)|No|1
|price|decimal(15,4)|No|0.0000
|points|int(8)|No|0
|tax_class_id|int(11)|No|
|date_available|date|No|
|weight|decimal(15,8)|No|0.00000000
|weight_class_id|int(11)|No|0
|length|decimal(15,8)|No|0.00000000
|width|decimal(15,8)|No|0.00000000
|height|decimal(15,8)|No|0.00000000
|length_class_id|int(11)|No|0
|subtract|tinyint(1)|No|1
|minimum|int(11)|No|1
|sort_order|int(11)|No|0
|status|tinyint(1)|No|0
|date_added|datetime|No|0000-00-00 00:00:00
|date_modified|datetime|No|0000-00-00 00:00:00
|viewed|int(5)|No|0
== Dumping data for table product

|886|BA-HANDBAGS-001ss|8| | | | | | |aaaa|95|7|data/hand-bags.jpg|7|0|25.0000|25|0|2012-09-03|0.00000000|1|0.00000000|0.00000000|0.00000000|1|1|1|1|1|2012-09-25 13:00:18|2012-09-25 14:15:09|0
```

Comment: We are not here to do your work for you. Subtracting two numbers is fairly easy in any programming language, so I'd suggest you look at which two numbers you want to subtract, and put a minus (`-`) sign between them. Oh, and read StackOverflow's [faq]

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be done quite easily in the PHP code for the cart as like:

```
$total=25;
$downpayment=13;
$remainingBalance = $total-$downpayment;
echo $remainingBalance;
```

Based on this and your previous question though, I would *really* suggest having a look through some basic PHP and SQL tutorials. Something [like this](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/php_tutorial_for_beginners/) will probably go a long way to help you get through these sort of issues you are coming up against. Now, I am not saying *don't ask*, I am thinking though that you might learn a heck of a lot on the way.

Comment: this is not what i mean... if u know about opencart checkout system can you please explain how to add downpayment field my confirm order section..?